# Docker force container to specific physical interface

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I've been searching around the internet for the past week or so to find a solution to this, but so far I have come up empty handed.

There are three network interfaces available to my host, and I need to execute a phantomjs script on the wlan1 interface.

My idea was to utilize Docker, but am running into issues locking a container to a specific interface.

Here's what I've tried, all either redirects to another interface, or has no network access. The only method that allows explicit access to the interface I need is by turning off all other interfaces.

`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -b=wlan1 --ip=10.0.0.151 -H fd://
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"

networks:
  open_network_1:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.host_binding_ipv4: "10.0.0.151"

services:
  open_wifi_phantomjs:
    image: https://github.com/ollihoo/phantomjs-docker-rpi
    networks:
      - open_network_1
    ports:
      - 10.0.0.151:80:80
      - 10.0.0.151:443:443
```

I've also fiddled with ip routing, and iptables

```
ip route del 172.19.0.0/16
ip route add 172.19.0.0/16 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.151
```

172.19 would be the subnet created by the docker-compose network, 10.0.0.151 would be the ip assigned to the wlan1 interface.

Any insight would be appreciated, and I'm sure will help those with similar goals.

Comment: So you want all your outgoing requests from the container to have a source address of the wlan1 ip, 10.0.0.151 and be routed out that interface?

Comment: May be this could help, the mcvlan part: http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/

Comment: That article actually helps a lot, thank you. Macvlan has a separate mac address than the physical adapter, using wifi, the controller bases authentication off of mac address. Parts about linux bridge would work splendid, but cannot link wifi adapters, and work arounds don't work with my drivers. I'm trying to run a phantomjs script to auto accept an open wifi agreement for internal speed testing. Phantomjs doesn't allow interface selection so Docker is currently my only hope. Still tinkering with PID routing, may be onto something.

Comment: I found a possible work around. I was able to set the default route to my wireless gateway: `route add default gw 10.0.0.1`, seeing available routes with the `route` command. However this changes for the host, and not specifically for a Docker container but will work for my purposes.